# TCL Expect Sending $expect_out(buffer) at Login Prompt

Tags: tcl, expect

Expect is sending $expect_out(buffer) when prompted for user credentials instead of the designated variable ($user).  It then times out.  Below is the code:

```
...
    }
    "yes" {
        send_user "\nEnter your username for the WLC supporting the new APs:\n"
        sleep 6
    }
}
expect {
    -re "(.*)\n" {
        set user $expect_out(1,string)
    }
}
send_user "\nEnter your password for the WLC supporting the new APs:\n"
sleep 15
expect {
    -re "(.*)\n" {
        set pass $expect_out(1,string)
    }
}
sleep 1
send_user "\nSshing to the IP of the WLC supporting the new APs ($wlc_temp)\n"
spawn ssh $wlc_temp

expect {
    "User:" {
        send $user\n
        sleep 1
    }
}
expect {
    "assword:" {
        send $pass\n
        sleep 1
    }
}
```

Below is the result:

> (device hostname) User: (device hostname)
> User:

Below are the debugs:

> Sshing to the IP of the WLC supporting the new APs ()
> spawn ssh 
> parent: waiting for sync byte
> parent: telling child to go ahead
> parent: now unsynchronized from child spawn: returns {7153}
>
> expect: does "" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "User:"? no
>
> expect: does "\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "User:"? no
> (device hostname) User:
>
> expect: does "\r\n(device hostname) User:"
> (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "User:"? yes
> expect: set expect_out(0,string) "User:" expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
> expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\r\n(device hostname) User:"
> send: sending "\n" to { exp6 }
>
> expect: does " " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "assword:"? no
>
> (device hostname) User:
>
> expect: does "\r\n(device hostname) User:" (spawn_id exp6) match glob
> pattern "assword:"? no
> expect: timed out

**Update:**
Relocating the statements requesting user input to the top of the script served as a work around.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to read input from the user, you should use `expect_user` instead of `expect`:

```
        send_user "\nEnter your username for the WLC supporting the new APs:\n"
        sleep 6
    }
}
expect_user {
    -re "(.*)\n" {
        set user $expect_out(1,string)
    }
}
send_user "\nEnter your password for the WLC supporting the new APs:\n"
sleep 15
expect_user {
    -re "(.*)\n" {
        set pass $expect_out(1,string)
    }
}
sleep 1
send_user "\nSshing to the IP of the WLC supporting the new APs ($wlc_temp)\n"

# ...
```

(I also think that you could use fewer `sleep` calls in there, and instead just tune up the timeouts, but that's less likely to have an effect on the correct operation of the script.)

Comment: I made the changes you recommended, but am still seeing the same behavior.